# If $X$ is infinite and $x \in X$ , show $X \thicksim X \setminus \big\{x \big\}$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that If $X$ is infinite and $x \in X$ , show $X \thicksim  X  \setminus \big\{x \big\}$.

here ~ is an equivalence relation meaning they must have same cardinality

So far I have said:

Let $x_{n} = \big\{x_{1} , x_{2}, x_{3}, \ldots \big\}$ where $x_n \in X \setminus \big\{x \big\}$.
We are looking for a bijection from $x \rightarrow X\setminus \big\{x \big\}$

Here I am having trouble with the bijection. 
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(y)=
\begin{cases}
c_{1}&\text{if }y=x\\
c_{i+1}&\text{if }y=c_{i}\\
y&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
\end{aligned}
$$

How do i prove the piecewise function to be onto and 1-1

Comment: "An equivalence relation"? What does "a set "equivalence relation" with another set" mean, anyway? I think that must probably mean that both sets are equipollent (= have the same cardinality).

Comment: Yes thats what i meant sorry. ~ basically means same cardinallity

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Nop, equipollent is fine: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Equipollent.html . The term is also used in logic,

Comment: @Omnomnomnom In fact I haven't seen that term used a lot, but I came to know tit when I studied set theory. My school had a rather strong set theory staff, and still has: A. Fraenkel, Sharon Shelah, etc., so I always thought that is the most accurate term...but now I really think it doesn't matter that much.

Answer (score 4):

One handy key result of use here is that every infinite set has a countable subset. So, let $C=\{c_{1},c_{2},\ldots\}$ be a countable subset of $X\setminus \{x\}$. Define $f\colon X\to X\setminus\{x\}$ as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(y)=
\begin{cases}
c_{1}&\text{if }y=x\\
c_{i+1}&\text{if }y=c_{i}\\
y&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, prove that $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: thanks! now i just show f(y) is onto and one-to-one right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: ok Im having trouble cuz Its a piecewise function. I know for proving its one-to-one (injective) I show that if f(x)=f(y), then x=y but im having trouble cuz its piecewise

Comment: Try using the contrapositive: $a\not=b\implies f(a)\not=f(b)$.

Comment: im having trouble proving it is onto

Comment: Let $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$. If $y\notin C$, then $f(y)=y$. Otherwise, $y=c_{1}\implies f(x)=y$ and $y=c_{i}$, where $i>1\implies f(c_{i-1})=y$.